# Ubuntu Server DC with Samba server 4.4.5 forwarder question

Tags: networking, server, samba, dns

So I've decided to set up a DC via Samba 4 @ my 16.04 Ubuntu server . Question is - since my domain name is SAME as a hosted website domain name somwhere in the WWW (let's call it askubuntu.com) and since my smb.conf forwarder points to google DNS (or any other public one) a host pointed to my Dc as a DNS now answers with a Non-authorative answer to somwhere else than my local network. How to set Sambas DNS answer to my local net addr (my DC's ip addr) insted of being forwarded to googles and aswered by that one? 
Thanks --Virven.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your `/etc/network/interfaces` file

```
dns-nameservers local.ip.address
dns-search yourdomain.name
```